# file upload in react and node js not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i am trying very hard to upload file but no way i could find a clear solution .
i have tried many ways but not working .  Now the console shows me 200 and give me message that file is uploaded but file is not going in the folder . i ahve checked file size limit and folder is ok but dont know why its not working. could any help please.

///react component

```
 import { saveBasicUser, getOneBasicUser, uploadFile } from 
 '../../actions/basicAction';

 this.state = { file: []};

 handleChange(event) {

 this.setState({
 [event.target.name]: event.target.value, 
 file: 
 event.target.files}) 
 }

 handleSubmit(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
   var file = this.state.file

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    // console.log(obj);
    console.log(formData);

    //  this.props.dispatch(saveBasicUser(obj ))
     this.props.dispatch(uploadFile(formData ))
  }


<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">  
<input type="file" name = "file" onChange={this.handleChange} />
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</button>
```

////////action part

```
 export function uploadFile(formData) {
  console.log(formData)
  return (dispatch) => {

    return axios.post('/upload_file', {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
      data: formData
    }).then(function (res) {  

      console.log(res)
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(" err")
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
```

//////server part

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads')
},
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+ path.extname(file.originalname))
  }
})


var upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: {fileSize : 1000000} }).single('file');


app.post('/upload_file', function(req, res){

        upload(req, res, function(err) {
          if(err) {
              return res.end("Error uploading file.");
          }
          res.end("File is uploaded");
      });

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution at last.

react JS

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import Messages from '../Messages';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import { getOneBasicUser ,uploadFile} from '../../actions/basicAction';
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Upload extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };


        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFile = this.handleFile.bind(this);
      }
      //--------------------------------------------------------------------
      //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
      }
      //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      handleFile(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var id = this.props.params.id;

            console.log(id);

            var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

            var isFileExist = !!$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0];



            if (isFileExist) {

                $.ajax({

                    url:  '/upload_file/'+ id,

                    type: 'POST',

                    data: formData,

                    xhr: function () {

                        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

                        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {

                            if (e.lengthComputable) {

                                $('progress').attr({value: e.loaded, max: e.total});

                                $('#status').empty().text(parseInt((e.loaded / e.total * 100)) + '%');

                            }

                        }, false);

                        return xhr;

                    }.bind(this),

                    success: function (data) {

                        this.setState({

                            data: data

                        });

                        $('#status').empty().text('File Uploaded!');

                    }.bind(this),

                    error: function (xhr, status, err) {

                        console.log( err);

                    }.bind(this),

                    cache: false,

                    contentType: false,

                    processData: false

                });

            } else {

                $('#status').empty().text('Please choose the file.');

            }

            }
      //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      render() {




        return (
          <div className="container ca-container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12">
                <h2> Upload File </h2>
                <hr />
              </div>
            </div>
               <form onSubmit={this.handleFile} encType="multipart/form-data">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                <h3 id="status" className ="label label-success"></h3>
                <div className="form-group">
                      <label>
                        Name:
                   </label>
                      <input  type="file" className="form-control" name="BasicUserFile"  onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="file" />
                    </div>
                  <div className="btn-group" role="group">
                  <button type="submit" value="Upload File" className="btn btn-success btn-lg">Upload</button>
                  </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }



}
// ======================== REDUX CONNECTORS ========================
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    //basicUser: state.basicUser.basicUser

  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Upload);
```

////server.js

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads')
},
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    var basic_id = req.params.id 
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + basic_id+ path.extname(file.originalname))
  }
})


var upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: {fileSize : 1000000} }).single('BasicUserFile');


app.post('/upload_file/:id', function(req, res){

  console.log("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")

  console.log(req.params)

  console.log("000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")




        upload(req, res, function(err) {
          if(err) {
              return res.end("Error uploading file.");
          }
          res.end("File is uploaded");
      });

  });
```